# How to create a List of Wildcard elements Scala

Tags: scala, wildcard

I'm trying to write a function that returns a list (for querying purposes) that has some wildcard elements:

```
def createPattern(query: List[(String,String)]) = {

   val l = List[(_,_,_,_,_,_,_)]

   var iter = query

   while(iter != null) {
       val x = iter.head._1 match {
        case "userId" => 0
        case "userName" => 1
        case "email" => 2
        case "userPassword" => 3
        case "creationDate" => 4
        case "lastLoginDate" => 5
        case "removed" => 6
   }

     l(x) = iter.head._2
     iter = iter.tail
   }
   l
}
```

So, the user enters some query terms as a list.  The function parses through these terms and inserts them into `val l`.  The fields that the user doesn't specify are entered as wildcards.

Val l is causing me troubles.  Am I going the right route or are there better ways to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `List[(_,_,_,_,_,_,_)]` is not a value, it's a type. It's a "list of 7-tupes, each element of of which are of some definite but unknown type," more or less. The underscores in this context are shorthand for unconstrained existential types. It's unlikely this is anything like what you intend.

Answer (score 4):

Gosh, where to start. I'd begin by getting an IDE (IntelliJ / Eclipse) which will tell you when you're writing nonsense and why.

Read up on how `List` works. It's an immutable linked list so your attempts to update by index are very misguided.

Don't use tuples - use case classes.

You shouldn't ever need to use `null` and I guess here you mean `Nil`.

Don't use `var` and `while` - use for-expression, or the relevant higher-order functions `foreach`, `map` etc.

Your code doesn't make much sense as it is, but it seems you're trying to return a 7-element list with the second element of each tuple in the input list mapped via a lookup to position in the output list.

To improve it... don't do that. What you're doing (as programmers have done since arrays were invented) is to use the index as a crude proxy for a Map from Int to whatever. What you want is an actual `Map`. I don't know what you want to do with it, but wouldn't it be nicer if it were from these key strings themselves, rather than by a number? If so, you can simplify your whole method to

```
def createPattern(query: List[(String,String)]) = query.toMap
```

at which point you should realise you probably don't need the method at all, since you can just use `toMap` at the call site.

If you insist on using an `Int` index, you could write

```
def createPattern(query: List[(String,String)]) = {
  def intVal(x: String) = x match {
    case "userId" => 0
    case "userName" => 1
    case "email" => 2
    case "userPassword" => 3
    case "creationDate" => 4
    case "lastLoginDate" => 5
    case "removed" => 6
  }
  val tuples = for ((key, value) <- query) yield (intVal(key), value)
  tuples.toMap
}
```

Comment: Hi Luigi, Thanks for the advice! I was intending this function to output a 7tuple with missing items so that a discreet 7tuple can be compared like so: `(userId, userName, email, userPassword, creationDate, lastLoginDate, removed) == (*,*,email,*,creationDate,*,removed)` ?  Do you think .toMap will still work in that case? Wouldn't your model generate a hashcode for `(*,*,email,*,creationDate,*,removed)` that is very different from `(userId, userName, email, userPassword, creationDate, lastLoginDate, removed)`, supposing `email`, `creationDate` and `removed` are the same value?

Comment: I'm sorry, am I understanding you correctly? Sorry if I was unclear in my original question

Comment: @Alex It looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel, in quite a weird way. If you're querying a database you should use SQL, or a library like Slick (http://slick.typesafe.com/) that will allow you to write the queries in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do with the resulting list, but you can't create a List of wildcards like that.

What do you want to do with the resulting list, and what type should it be?

Here's how you might build something if you wanted the result to be a List[String], and if you wanted wildcards to be "*":

```
def createPattern(query:List[(String,String)]) = {
    val wildcard = "*"
    def orElseWildcard(key:String) = query.find(_._1 == key).getOrElse("",wildcard)._2
    orElseWildcard("userID") ::
    orElseWildcard("userName") ::
    orElseWildcard("email") ::
    orElseWildcard("userPassword") ::
    orElseWildcard("creationDate") ::
    orElseWildcard("lastLoginDate") ::
    orElseWildcard("removed") ::
    Nil
}
```

Comment: Hi Brandon, I intend to use the result to compare against a User database.  Each insertion in the database has values for each field:
(userId, userName, email, userPassword, creationDate, lastLoginDate, removed).  The search function will contain a list of terms to search for.  Lets say, for example, that the user searching decides to specify (email, creationDate, removed).  I want to match every User in the database with these specific fields, but all else wildcard.  Like:
`(userId, userName, email, userPassword, creationDate, lastLoginDate, removed) == (*,*,email,*,creationDate,*,removed)` ?

Comment: If you're going to use this to build an SQL query, or a query using some database library, there are probably more useful representations than a list (or tuple) of strings with wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using List, Tuple, iterator, or wild-cards correctly.
I'd take a different approach - maybe something like this:

```
case class Pattern ( valueMap:Map[String,String] ) {
    def this( valueList:List[(String,String)] ) = this( valueList.toMap )

    val Seq(
            userId,userName,email,userPassword,creationDate,
            lastLoginDate,removed
          ):Seq[Option[String]] = Seq( "userId", "userName", 
               "email", "userPassword", "creationDate", "lastLoginDate",
               "removed" ).map( valueMap.get(_) )
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
scala> val pattern = new Pattern( List( "userId" -> "Fred" ) )
pattern: Pattern = Pattern(Map(userId -> Fred))

scala> pattern.email
res2: Option[String] = None

scala> pattern.userId
res3: Option[String] = Some(Fred)
```

, or just use the map directly.